# UITextView in a grouped UITableView's cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextview

Please, explain me: how to programmatically create an UITextView in UITableViewCell (UITableView has a grouped style). The text view size should be equal to size of the cell.

The UITextView has a gap between its text and its border (top left corner), so I need the correct coordinates to properly place the text view on a cell.

**UPDATE**: I've solved my question. See my self-answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to show your current code in your question so that people could suggest improvements.

Comment: create the instance of `UITextView` object and add it to your `UITableCellView` as a subview, and make sure when you reuse any old `UITableCell`, don't add a new instance of `UITextView` to same cell again if you don't want to waste the memory unnecessarily.

Comment: I've edited the question for better clarity.

Comment: To mark your question as solved, accept the answer, don't update the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple:

```
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Prototype Cell"];
    UITextField *textfield;
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Prototype Cell"];
        textfield = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textfield];
        textfield.tag = TEXT_FIELD_TAG; //Suppose you defined TEXT_FIELD_TAG someplace else
    }
    else 
    {
        textfield = [self.view viewWithTag: TEXT_FIELD_TAG];
        textfield.frame = cell.frame;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I want to create an UITextView object, not UITextField. The UITextView has a gap between its text and its border (top left corner), so I need the correct coordinates to properly place the text view on a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Set "contentInset" of UITextView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *sCellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDetail
                                      reuseIdentifier:sCellIdentifier];
    }
    UITextView *textView = [UITextView alloc]init];
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-8,-8,-8); //Change according ur requirement
    textView.frame = cell.frame;
    [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubView:textView];
    return cell;
}
```